# check if pandas dataframe is dataframe or series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, spyder

What is the best way to check if a dataframe is a Pandas.Dataframe or pandas.Series?

Comment: [isinstance()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/type-isinstance-python/)

Answer (score 13):

to expand on Ryan's comment:

`isinstance(df,pd.DataFrame)` will return `True` if it is a dataframe. to check if it is a series, it would be `isinstance(df,pd.Series)`.

Answer (score 2):

Another way of doing it:

`type(your_object)`